# Javascript: Wait for AJAX call to finish before initiating user triggered action

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page sends out an ajax calls as part of page load and the response takes ~5 seconds

I take result from the ajax call and store it in a hidden div.

Now after page is rendered , there is a table (JQuery Datatable) , and each table row has some action buttons (view, edit , delete), which the user can click.

Some of these actions need the data from the div.

So if the user clicks any of those actions before the Ajax is complete, the action fails, but it will work fine in case Ajax call is complete.

Can I add a wait/sleep logic to those calls/code, so that if the use click the actions, it just waits for AJAX response, rather than enabling the action buttons as callback or failure and the user doesn't have to click the button again.

I tried adding a function with setTimeout logic, but it breaks my model.

Ajax Call

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax?AJAXKeyword=keyword",
            success: function(result){
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $( "#div" ).html( result );
            });


          }
          })
```

OnClick Action which needs the data

```
                .on('click', 'a.show-row', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    doPoll1();
                })
```

```
function doPoll1(){

            if( $("#div").text().length == 0) {
                setTimeout(doPoll1,1000);
            } else {
            === myActions ===
            }
        }
```

I would like the execution of JS Code to sleep/wait in case the data is not present.

Comment: you can do this in your ajax code. can you please paste your ajax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So you have 2 different ajax call one loading Datatable another loading Div.**

In that case

1 Either load div first and than call Datatable

2 Disable all buttons by default and enable when Div is loaded. Keep a divLoaded variable globally as boolean.
In that case user will not be able to click button.

3 Keep track of all button clicked before Div was loaded and once div is loaded, do action for clicked row record.

**If you have Data in Datatable call itself. This is way to get row data on button click.**

Instead of saving data in a separate Div you can get clicked Row data from Datatable API itself and this will avoid ajax load call issue.

Sample Edit Row event:

```
$('.dt-edit').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function(evt){
        $this = $(this);
        var dtRow = $this.parents('tr');
        $('div.modal-body').innerHTML='';
        $('div.modal-body').append('Row index: '+dtRow[0].rowIndex+'<br/>');
        $('div.modal-body').append('Number of columns: '+dtRow[0].cells.length+'<br/>');
        for(var i=0; i < dtRow[0].cells.length; i++){
            $('div.modal-body').append('Cell (column, row) '+dtRow[0].cells[i]._DT_CellIndex.column+', '+dtRow[0].cells[i]._DT_CellIndex.row+' => innerHTML : '+dtRow[0].cells[i].innerHTML+'<br/>');
        }
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

`dtRow` will contain all fields needed for that particular row.

Refer [this](https://codepen.io/RedJokingInn/pen/zZyRmR) for demo

Comment: Data in div is ~ 300kB in size. It is not already present on the page/table and is shared by all the rows. Something like a drop down of Countries, but different data.

Comment: added more detail

Comment: Either load div first and than call Datatable -- This seems the best response, though It would slow down the overall rendering of the page. I implemented serer side caching/scheduled refreshing of cache to reduce the AJAX processing time though.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do easily is show a loading icon and disable the buttons until the ajax loads.

```
function waiting(btnState){
  $('btn.waitAjaxXY').attr("disabled", btnState);
  if(btnState)
   $('displayLoadGif').show()
  else
   $('displayLoadGif').hide()
}

$.Ajax({...... waiting(true)}).always(function(){waiting(false)})
```

This example is pretty raw but i hope it helps you.
It's better if you show the user why they can't push the button and how long since it's frustrating if just wont do the action i asked for.